# CSS: horizontally overflowing elements start new line

Tags: html, css

When you have children that, together, exceed the width of their parent, a new vertical line will be created to account for the space. But I moved one of my children over.

```css
.parent {
  height: 200px;
  width: 250px;
  background-color: pink;
  margin: auto;
}

.child {
  height: 75px;
  width: 150px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: brown;
  outline: 1px solid black;
}

.child:last-of-type {
  left: -100px
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Any way I can get the divs to be on the same line now? Due to the real world situation, it would be ideal to not set them to position absolute, though I suspect that may be the only answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Flexbox` to place your children `div` in the same line

> [JsFiddle](https://jsbin.com/yehuleduse/1/edit?html,output)

```
  .parent {
    height: 200px;
    width: 250px;
    background-color: pink;
    margin: auto;
    display: flex;
  }
  .child {
    height: 75px;
    flex: 1 0 150px;
    background-color: brown;
    outline: 1px solid black;
  }
```

---

**Result**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you

CSS

```
.parent {
    height: 200px;
    width: 250px;
    background-color: pink;
    margin: auto;
  }
  .child {
    height: 75px;
    width: 150px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: brown;
    outline: 1px solid black;
    float: left;
  }
.last {
  width:100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="last"><div class="child"></div></div>
  </div>
```

Codepen
https://codepen.io/YasirKamdar/pen/qxjLNZ

Comment: you elements are overlapping

Comment: Maybe I didn’t get the question right, I thought the blocks were suppose to fit in the parent, and the overflow section here is hidden.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.parent {
  height: 200px;
  width: 250px;
  background-color: pink;
  margin: auto;
  white-space:nowrap;
  font-size:0;
}

.child {
  height: 75px;
  width: 150px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: brown;
  outline: 1px solid black;
  display:inline-block;
  white-space:normal;
  font-size:12px; /* your original font-size*/
}

.child:last-of-type {
  left: -100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Should work also in IE8 due to not use flexbox.